# Salesforce Password Expired

Tags: passwords, reset-password

My salesforce password expired for unknown reasons. The password policy is set to expire the password every year and it's only been 4 months. Has anyone encountered this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at the password policies for the org, but you most likely have [Profile Password Policies](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_password_policies.htm&type=5) defined which override it.

> To ensure that the appropriate level of password security is used for
> your organization, specify password requirements with Password
> Policies settings for users assigned to a profile. **Profile Password
> Policies settings override the organization-wide Password Policies for
> that profile’s users**. If you do not set Password Policies on a
> profile, the organization-wide Password Policies apply.

Go to your profile and scroll down to see Password Policies

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked at the profile level too and it's one year

Comment: And for the 4 months, you're basing that off of `Last Password Change or Reset` on your user record?

Comment: Oh where do I check that in setup?

Comment: If you go to your user record (user icon in top right corner --> Settings --> Advanced User Details), it's a field.